# how to exclude some specific django permissions in django html template

Tags: django, user-permissions

I am trying to display the user permissions which are relevant to my project excluding some default django user permissions. I am implementing the following code. I want to exclude permissions like sessions, content_type, groups from my html template. How can i do it??

> views.py

```
permissions = Permission.objects.all()
```

> template

*I want to remove user can add group,user can change group in template*

```
{% for permission in permissions %}
{{permission.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the fields of permission object, you can find a field named `content_type`. Content_type specifies the `app_label` and `model` from which you can be able to exclude the permissions defined for **users, groups, sessions, etc.**

For example, you can find the content_type ids of models **user, group, session, etc.** as:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
content_type_ids = []  # a list to store the ids of the content_type object which you want to exclude

# for user model
content_type_ids.append(ContentType.objects.get(model='user').id)
# for session model
content_type_ids.append(ContentType.objects.get(model='session').id)
# for group model
content_type_ids.append(ContentType.objects.get(model='group').id)

# exclude the Permissions having content_type_id obtained
permissions = Permission.objects.exclude(content_type_id__in=content_type_ids)
```

In such manner you can get the content type ids for each models you want to not show in the template and exclude them.

I did try it myself and although it is a lengthy process, I hope someone else has a better solution to it that is more effective and faster.